# Can POSIX named semaphores synchronize threads?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, posix, semaphore

I am looking for a way to synchronize several multi-threaded processes on Linux.
C++11-style mutexes only operate among threads within a single process,
ans as far as I know, flock doesn't mutually excludes threads of the same process.

Therefore, I was thinking of POSIX semaphores.
I know that unnamed semaphores are either thread- or process-related, but not both.
What about named semaphores? Obviously they synchronize processes, but what about threads? I could not find the clear definitive answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they synchronize threads.

The Open Group Base Specification Issue 7 clarifies under **General Concepts** that all [semaphores synchronize threads](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_16_00_01), whether they are POSIX-style (`<semaphore.h>`) or SysV-style (`<sys/sem.h>`):

> *[T]the semaphore lock operation shall cause the calling thread to be blocked and added to the set of threads awaiting the semaphore*

Regarding your remark that *"unnamed semaphores are either thread- or process-related, but not both"*, I don't quite know what you mean.  Unnamed semaphores may be *shared* between (parent-child) processes if allocated in shared memory and [explicitly initialized as "pshared"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_init.html).  However, process-shared or not, unnamed semaphores synchronize individual threads.

(For what it's worth, POSIX mutexes may also [be shared between processes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html).)